# How to add -v switch without needing a switch for the filename using GetOpt?

Tags: perl

I want to be able to run my script in one of two ways:

```
perl script.pl file  
perl script.pl -v file
```

I know how to do

```
perl script.pl -v -f file
```

But I want to do it without needing the -f for file.

Comment: Can you show what you tried and give the errors you saw?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After using `GetOpt`, the remaining items in `@ARGV` are your positional parameters. You just need to use `$ARGV[0]` for "file".

```
use Getopt::Long;

my $verbose = 0;
my %opts = ( 'verbose' => \$verbose );
GetOptions(\%opts, 'verbose|v') or die "Incorrect options";
my $file = $ARGV[0];
die "You must provide a filename" unless length $file;
```

Comment: It's `Getopt::Long`, not `GetOpt::Long`.

Comment: You might also want to say `unless length $file` unless you have something against files named `0`.

Answer (score 2):

You can use [Getopt::Long's argument callback](https://metacpan.org/module/JV/Getopt-Long-2.39/lib/Getopt/Long.pm#Argument-callback):

```
use Getopt::Long;                                                                                                                                                                                          

my $file;                                                                                                                                                                                                  
GetOptions(                                                                                                                                                                                                
    'v' => \my $v,                                                                                                                                                                                         
    '<>' => sub { $file = shift },                                                                                                                                                                         
);                                                                                                                                                                                                         

print "\$v: $v\n";                                                                                                                                                                                         
print "\$file: $file\n";
```

The command `perl script.pl -v foo.txt` outputs:

```
$v: 1
$file: foo.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

[Getopt::Long](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) parses (by default) the items in `@ARGV` and removes these items one-by-one as it processes `@ARGV`. After `Getoptions` finishes, the first item remaining in `@ARGV` will be the file name:

```
use warnings;
use strict;
use Getopt::Long;

my $verbose;

GetOptions (
    'v'  =>  "\$verbose",
) or die qq(Invalid arguments passed);

my $file = shift;  #Assuming a single file. Could be multiple
if ( $verbose ) {
    print "Do something verbosely\n";
}
else {
    print "Do it the normal way...\n";
}
```

Nothing special is needed. You allow `GetOptions` to handle the `-v` parameter if it exists, and you allow `@ARGV` to contain all of the parameters that are left after `GetOptions` finishes executing.

By the way, you could do this:

```
GetOptions (
    'verbose'  =>  "\$verbose",
) or die qq(Invalid arguments passed);
```

And you could use:

```
perl script.pl -v file
```

or
    perl script.pl -verbose file

or

```
perl script.pl -verb file
```

Because, by default, `GetOptions` will [auto_abbreviate](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html#Configuring-Getopt%3a%3aLong) the parameters and figure out what parameters the user is attempting to pass.

I highly recommend you look at the [documentation](http://perldoc.perl.org/Getopt/Long.html) and play around with it a bit. There will be a lot of stuff that won't quite make sense to you, but this is probably one of the earliest modules that new Perl programmers start to use, and it is full of all sorts of neat stuff.

And keep going back and reread the documentation as your skills develop because you'll find new stuff in this module as your understanding of Perl increases.